# Filter out columns from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to filter out all columns where the value in row "b" is >2% of the sum of all rows in a given column.

```
df
   x   y    z
a  99  95  99
b  1   4    1
c  0   1    0
```

```
result
   x   z  
a  99  99
b  1   1
c  0   0
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's the use case? Or is it just an exercise?

Comment: if you transpose you data.frame your question becomes much more straightforward and the solution much simpler I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1[, df1["b", ]/colSums(df1) <= 0.02 ]
#    x  z
# a 99 99
# b  1  1
# c  0  0
```